# How to use "request_contact" and "request_location" fields in "KeyboardButton" Object on Telegram Bot API

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I want to try get user phone using telegram bot API. I found a method on this : https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton

I have try but still not solve, here is my code :

```
        $replyMarkup3 =array(
                            'keyboard' => array(
                            array('text'=>'test'),

                            'request_contact'=>true,
                            'request_location'=>true,
                                ),
                            'resize_keyboard'=>true,
                            'one_time_keyboard'=>true,

                                );
        $encodedMarkup = json_encode($replyMarkup3);
        $data =    $this->tele->sendMessage($this->user_id2,$content,$parse_mode=null, true, null, $encodedMarkup);
        print_r($data); die();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Telegram Doc](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton) says: "Optional fields are mutually exclusive."  This means that you only can use `request_contact` field or `request_location` .You can NOT use both of them togeher.

Also , `keyboard` MUST be array of arrays of `KeyboardButton` object.
This is a working sample `replyMarkup` you can use instead:

```
$replyMarkup3 =[
    'keyboard' =>[ [ [
        'text'=>'test',
        'request_contact'=>true,
    ]]],
    'resize_keyboard'=>true,
    'one_time_keyboard'=>true,
];
```

Comment: wow amazing, thanks friend ! it works. may i know your email?? or maybe your facebook account? i really want discuss or ask more and more :)

Comment: @IIMNURDIANSYAH, If it was helpful why you do not vote up ?  Did you read [this doc?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) before?

Comment: hi @Tick Tock, can you teach me how send mesage on inline mode and how to reply it? i have read the documentation but i need an example

Comment: @IIMNURDIANSYAH , hi , I've not worked with inline mode yet.but I think they should similar, except you should use `inline methods` instead. Best wishes